Azure Modules Fail to Import in Azure Automation Runbooks - Import-Module: Cannot access Azure\PSConfig.json
Import-Module: The process cannot access the file C:\Users\username\.Azure\PSConfig.json because it is being used by another process. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AZ.Accounts\2.8.0\Az.Accounts.psm1:117
This error occurs when my Azure Automation triggers multiple PowerShell runbooks to start at the same time and they try to Connect-AZAccount. From what I have been able to gather, this file is locked down when a script accesses it, so the rest of the runbooks fail for not being able to recognize Azure module cmdlets.
I've tried to mitigate this by reimporting the Az.Accounts module but it never seems to work. It will import the module but still the script thinks it doesn't recognize any Azure module cmdlets. Any thoughts?
$try = 20
do {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-Module Az.Accounts))) {
        Write-Output "Importing AZ.Accounts"
        Import-Module AZ.Accounts
    }
    try {
        Connect-AzAccount -Identity -Subscription $SubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to connect to Azure! $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    }
    $AZContext = Get-AzContext
    $try--
} while ($AZContext.Subscription.Id -ne $SubscriptionId -OR $try -le 0)



Azure Modules Fail to Import in Azure Automation Runbooks - Import-Module: Cannot access Azure\PSConfig.json:

The issue is due to all the PowerShell automation runbooks are trying to access the PSConfig.Json at a time simultaneously. That is why the file locks are occurring.
Check below to resolve the conflict:
1.
As the issue coming while performing the Azure login accounts operation, you can try using managed identity to authenticate instead of going with the credentials.
Managed identity login doesn't require any credentials to hold and only require the -identity parameter as shown below.
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

2.
According to the SO by @Jenny Hunter for the similar issue, it would be better that you can serialize the runbooks to avoid conflicts and run operations at the same time.
3.
As you are already mentioned this approach, you can use below logical script to handle the file locks scenarios.
$retry = 0
$tries = xxx #User requirement
$wait = xxxx Eg: 5
do {
    try {
        if (-not (Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts)) {
            Write-Output "Importing AZAccounts"
            Import-Module Az.Accounts
        }

        Connect-AzAccount -Identity -ErrorAction Stop
        $Context = Get-AzContext
        $conn = $true
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "$($_.Exception.Message)"
        $retry++
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $wait
        $wait *= 2
        $conn = $false
    }
} 
while (-not $conn -and $retry -lt $tries)


4.
Alternatively, using Disable-AzContextAutosave may resolve the conflict in this scenario.
As it,

Turn off autosaving Azure credentials. Your login information will be forgotten the next time you open a PowerShell window.

Refer MSDoc for the same information in a more detailed way.
